# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед союзом "и"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Мама устала от работы, от разговоров со старшим сыном на счет оценок и ждет очередного обещания, что сын исправится.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Мама устала от работы, от разговоров со старшим сыном **насчет** оценок и ждет очередного обещания, что сын исправится.

**Не надо запятой:** мама устала и ждёт, однородные сказуемые, одиночный союз И.

**Только вот стиль  предложения не самый лучший**: повтор слова *сын*, также нелогична связь сказуемых: устала и ждет. Почему их связывает соединительный союз?

Answer (score 1):

Корректно:

> Мама устала от работы и от разговоров со старшим сыном **насчет** оценок **в надежде получить обещание, что он исправится**.

или

> Мама устала от работы, от разговоров со старшим сыном **насчет оценок и от обещаний, что он исправится**.

1. Запятая перед союзом *и* не нужна, потому что он соединяет однородные сказуемые (устала и ждет), однако предложение лучше переформулировать:

   - заменяем часть «и ждет очередного обещания, что сын исправится» на «в надежде получить обещание, что он исправится» и избавляемся от трудной пунктуационной ситуации и проблем с повтором;
   - вставляем союз *и* между однородными дополнениями «от работы» и «от разговоров», чтобы было удобнее читать.
2. Предлог *насчет* в значении предлога *о* пишется в одно слово.

Comment: По-моему, ваша правка не улучшила предложение. Лучше так: Мама устала от работы,  от разговоров со старшим сыном насчет оценок и от обещаний , что он исправится. Кстати, я надеялась, что автор вопроса сама предложит исправленный вариант, поэтому не предлагала своей редакции.

Comment: @Jasmin неплохой вариант, добавлю. Спасибо! А что не так с моим?

Comment: К слову "от разговоров" относятся три определения, причем сочетание "разговоры в надежде" мне кажется некорректным.

Comment: @Jasmin видимо, у нас разное чувство стиля: я не вижу ничего плохого в предложенном мной варианте. Что конкретно не так в трех определениях и сочетании «разговоры в надежде»?..